# Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: pandas, indexing, merge, concatenation, drop

Irun this code

```
esg_fm_barron = pd.concat([barron_clean.drop(columns = "10 year return", inplace = False),ESG_fixed.drop(columns = 'Name',inplace = False), financial_clean.drop(columns = 'Name',inplace = False)], axis = 'columns', join = 'inner')
esg_fm_barron.rename(columns={'Average (Current)': "Total ESG Score"}, inplace=True)
esg_fm_barron.head(3)
```

but is get this error : Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
does anyone know a solution ? thanks

Answer (score 11):

When you run *pd.concat*, each source DataFrame must have unique index.

First identify which source DataFrame has a non-unique index.
For each source DataFrame (assuming it is *df*) run:

```
df.index.is_unique
```

(this is a **property**, not a method, so put no parentheses).

The *false* result means that the index in this DataFrame is non-unique.
Then drop rows with duplicated index values:

```
df = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

In order not to loose original data, maybe you should save the result under
a new temporary DataFrame and then use for concatenation these temporary DataFrames.

Comment: I run this it works :D : 
'
esg_fm_barron = pd.merge(pd.merge(barron_clean,ESG_fixed,on='Ticker'),financial_clean,on='Ticker')
esg_fm_barron.drop(['Name', '10 year return','Name_y'] , axis=1, inplace=True)
esg_fm_barron.rename(columns={'Average (Current)': "Total ESG Score"}, inplace=True)
esg_fm_barron.rename(columns={'Name_x': "Name"}, inplace=True)
esg_fm_barron.head()'

Comment: Just a note, there, is not any method `.is_unique()`. Actually it is an attribute of the index object (maybe a property actually) so the test should be `df.index.is_unique`

Comment: You're right. I corrected my answer.